# What methods/objects in ZFC can't be computed and why not?

Tags: set-theory, computability, constructive-mathematics

I was reading the Wikipedia page for set theory and read the following passage:
"The most common objection to set theory, one Kronecker voiced in set theory's earliest years, starts from the constructivist view that mathematics is loosely related to computation. If this view is granted, then the treatment of infinite sets, both in naive and in axiomatic set theory, introduces into mathematics methods and objects that are not computable even in principle." Why not? What are such objects and why can't they be computed even in principle? Wikipedia listed no sources for this quote.

Comment: The axiom of choice and the law of excluded middle have no computational interpretation. Much of the stuff with infinity only works well in the presence of choice.

Comment: Chaitin's constant is a real number that cannot be computed since this would require to solve the halting problem. The Kolmogorov complexity is uncomputable in the sense that every algorithm trying that will fail for some instances.

Comment: Similar to something pointed out by Brouwer in his 1907 dissertation, under the full axiom of choice—and more generally the law of the excluded middle—the continuum of real numbers starts behaving like discrete, cleanly separated and individual points. Computationally, or as numerical analysts intuitively know, this is *not* how the real numbers appear; there is no way to probe the continuum, even in principle, as if it were an already completed and cleanly separated collection of points. All the unconstructive axioms essentially assert the existence of such a method in various different ways.